# What happens to paypal IPNs if no message sent back to PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

For a while I have been running a site which logs paypal transactions by sending a notify_url to the paypal site, and listens in on that notify_url. My listening page parses the IPN info sent from paypal, and returns an http 200 response, but it *doesn't* then "send the complete message back to PayPal using HTTPS POST" to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (point 3 at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/). The payments seems to have been going through OK. I want to know what problems I have been storing up for myself by not doing this response part of the IPN request-response flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have laid yourself open to accepting IPN messages that may not be from PayPal. The purpose of the message you're omitting is to ensure that the IPN you are processing came from PayPal.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that, and have various systems in place to mitigate hack attempts (although I should also do it properly!). But are there any issues from the paypal end, e.g. is the transaction not flagged as complete until the response is received?

Comment: I believe as long as you finish the transaction they are doing to you with a 200 back to them it's over. Anyway if they thought it wasn't, they would resend it. It's a very amateurish design if you ask me. Was there something wrong with sending a client certificate?